# Arduino SD card library non-blocking. Code tracing confusion

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I am confused by the conditional statement in the Arduino SD example, Non-Blocking Write.

[Arduino SD - Non Blocking Write Example - Github](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD/blob/master/examples/NonBlockingWrite/NonBlockingWrite.ino)

I don't understand why dataBuffer.length() could be greater than equal to chunkSize.

**If dataBuffer is 'greater than' chunkSize, would the data have a chance to become lost because the buffer could be longer than the available space to write on the SD card?**

I believe availableForWrite() is returning the number of bits available to write without causing any blocking. Similar to Serial.availableForWrite() - [Arduino_Doc_link](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/availableforwrite/)

Statement in Question

> if (chunkSize && dataBuffer.length() >= chunkSize) {

```
  // check if the SD card is available to write data without blocking
  // and if the dataBuffered data is enough for the full chunk size
  unsigned int chunkSize = myFile.availableForWrite();
  if (chunkSize && dataBuffer.length() >= chunkSize) { <----
    // write to file and blink LED
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    myFile.write(dataBuffer.c_str(), chunkSize);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    // remove written data from dataBuffer
    dataBuffer.remove(0, chunkSize);
  }
```

Comment: And `dataBuffer.remove(0, chunkSize);` is removing first `chunkSize` bytes from the dataBuffer, so it can continue next round from where it ended